# CSV file is shown as locked for editing while working with csv module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am working with csv module in python for the first time and I am using the with option to work with the csv file. I am closing the file,but when I open my csv file from file explorer using Excel, it shows that the file is locked for editing by "another user". Below is code snippet:

```
FinalData = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
        for row in FinalData:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
testfile.close()
```

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: the file is not opened by another application (e.g. MS Office). Have you tried turning your pc off and on again? The indention at `csv_writer.writerow` is wrong. The `with` statement takes care of closing the file, so the last line is unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe you also try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313472/-the-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-error-message-when-you-try-to-open-a-document-in-word

Comment: I ran your code and Excel opened the file.
Which Excel are you using? I used 2016 version BTW - testfile.close()
is unnecessary since the with is closing the file.

Comment: I am using Excel 2016, but still seeing the issue. @ppasler: did not see any win processes to kill under task manager.

Comment: Did you try deleting the `testfile.close()` line? As mentioned the `with` statement should take care.

Comment: Yup deleted the tesfile.close(), but the issue is there. Issue is not seen only after rebooting PC. I am using Pycharms application for my python files, I closed the program but the issue still exists.

Comment: After some trial and error, I found out the process whihc was hanging on to the excel file and giving me the error message. Now I am able to edit the document after successfully killing the process. Thanks for your comments.